# MQTT, is it possible to block publications for everyone besides localhost, and leave the subscriptions open to everybody?

Tags: mqtt, messagebroker

What I want to do is to have data published from localhost only.
But I need to allow any user in the web to subscribe to that topic, is it possible to do with MQTT? How?

If not, do I have any other options to fullfill this specifics.

Additional information:

- Using MQTT protocol to post.
- Using Websockets to subscribe.
- Using Mosquitto as broker.

Answer (score 1):

Most MQTT brokers support ACLs to limit access to topics to specific users. They also tend to allow a ACL for unauthenticated (annonymous) users.

So you should be able to define a specific user that you can use to publish from localhost and then set up an anonymous ACL that only allows subscriptions to #

For Mosquitto the acl file would look something like:

```
user publisher
pattern readwrite #

user anonymous
pattern read #
```

Comment: Thank you, exacly what I was looking for.